# Unable to run code snippet in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: python, json, visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I have attempted to run a code snippet from an individual tab in Visual Studio, but have not been successful in doing so. The code I am writing in is Python.

I have tried
Tools > Options > ...
But am unsure how to add a keyboard short-cut that will enable me to run a code snippet.
[Screenshot from VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLup6.png)

Essentially, my desired outcome is to be able to utilise a functionality in Visual Studio 2022 that is the same thing as the following functionality in MySQL workbench:
[Screenshot from MySQL Workbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUeJF.png)

I want to be able to execute a code snippet.
[Visual Studio Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqJYG.png)
In the screenshot above, I would simply like to run `print("hello1")` and not `print("hello2")`.
I would also like to only run code from the tab titled "module1.py" and not the two other tabs open. Having navigated around, I haven't been able to do so as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done. Visual Studio 2022 has support for C, C++, F# (basically OCaml), C# and maybe still VB.NET but no support for Python.